# First HTTP request takes 20 seconds to execute

Tags: react-native, expo

Our react native Android/IOS app is taking around 20 seconds for first HTTP request to complete. Any following request is working properly (few ms).

Here's what we know so far:

- Issue only happens on Android phones.
- Issue happens when "Debug JS Remotely" option is DISABLED, when debug is enabled it works fine.
- Our json server and Expo server are running on the same machine, we have noticed that when json server address (on mobile app) is switched to other developer's machine then there is no problem. So if Jack connects with his phone to Jill's json srv and vice versa it works. But when Jack connects with his phone to Jack's json srv it works not.
- We tried accessing json srv from phone chrome and it works instantly.
- Tried disabling IPv6 and few other solutions but to no avail.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue.
We had a circular dependency in our Axios using library which caused the problem.
Circular got lost within NativeBase circular dependancy warnings.
One more reason to deal with those seriusly...